# Toggle a function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to turn on and turn off a function on click - toggle a function.

I want `.fly` element to not disappear, only the animation should stop and return to its origin. When the button is clicked, the animation should stop. When it's clicked again, the animation starts again.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="hobbie-box">
      <div class="circle-image">
        <i id="travel" class="fa fa-plane fly"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="circle-text">
        <p>Travel industry</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn toggle-effects">Turn off effects</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
     var flyplane = function(){
      setInterval(function() {
        $fly.animate({
            right: '-=50',
            bottom: '+=50'
        }, 2000, function() {
            $fly.removeAttr("style");
        });
    }, 2000);
};
  flyplane();


$(".toggle-effects").on("click", function () {
        $(this).text(function (i, text) {
          return text === "Turn off effects" ? "Turn on effects" : "Turn off effects";
        })
        $("#travel").toggle($fly);
      }); //end of button click
```

Comment: You should put your CSS code, and the button's HTML code too, since it would be much easier for us to test and achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you need an event to be executed once after a delay you should use **setTimeout()** function nstead of **setInterval()**.

And instead of using `.animate` in JavaScript you can simply add a class `fly` to your element using `.toggleClass()` function.

This is a working snippet:

```js
var $fly = $('.fly');

var flyplane = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $fly.toggleClass('fly');
  }, 2000);
};

flyplane();

$(".toggle-effects").on("click", function() {
  $("#travel").toggle(0, flyplane);
}); //end of button click
```

```css
.fly{
  
      right: -50
      bottom: +50
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="hobbie-box">
  <div class="circle-image">
    <i id="travel" class="fa fa-plane"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-text">
    <p>Travel industry</p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="toggle-effects" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check for a var like this

```js
$fly = $(".fly")

fly = true

flyplane = function(){
        setInterval(function() {
          if(fly){
            $fly.animate({
                right: '-=50',
                bottom: '+=50'
            }, 2000, function() {
                $fly.removeAttr("style");
            });
          }
        }, 2000);
  
    };

$(".toggle-effects").on("click", function () {
  fly = !fly
});
```

```css
.fly{
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #00ff00;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fly"></div>
```

Comment: this is good but I need to toggle the fly=false to go back to true after the click event. Its should toggle between true and false on each click

Answer (score 0):

There is a live example.
Please refer to [my codepen](http://codepen.io/ssohjiro/pen/meObjr/)

```
 <div class="hobbie-box">
  <div class="circle-image">
    <i id="travel" class="fa fa-plane fly"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-text">
    <p>Travel industry</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class='toggle-effects'>[btn]</button>
```

```
#travel {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```
var $fly = $('.fly');

var flyplane = function() {

    $fly.animate({
      right: '-=50',
      bottom: '+=50'
    }, 2000, function() {
      console.log('animation complete')
      $fly.removeAttr("style");
      flyplane();
    });
};

//flyplane();
var count = 1;
$(".toggle-effects").on("click", function() {
  console.log('click');
  var isHidden = count++%2 !== 0;
  if( isHidden ) {
    $("#travel").show( 0, flyplane);  
  } else {
    $("#travel").hide( 0 );
      $fly.stop();
  }

}); //end of button click
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you are trying to achieve, but, if using `setInterval`:

- You must save it into a variable, e.g `variable = setInterval(function() { /* ... */ }, 2000);`
- To stop the interval, you must use `clearInterval`, e.g `clearInterval(variable);`.
- And then, to star the interval again, you must call `setInterval` again, so it's better to encapsulate your code into a function, so you don't need to rewrite the same code twice.
- Since, your `flyplane` function was already there, I only used it.

Take a look at the snippet below, and tell me if that's what you're trying to achive:

```js
$(function() {
  var $fly = $('.fly'), interval;
  var flyplane = function() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      $fly.animate({
        right: '-=50',
        bottom: '+=50'
      }, 2000, function() {
        $fly.removeAttr("style");
      });
    }, 2000);
  };
  flyplane();


  $(".toggle-effects").on("click", function() {
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
      if (text === "Turn off effects") {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return "Turn on effects";
      }
      else {
        flyplane();
        return "Turn off effects";
      }
    })
  }); //end of button click
});
```

```css
.fly {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hobbie-box">
  <div class="circle-image">
    <i id="travel" class="fa fa-plane fly"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-text">
    <p>Travel industry</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn toggle-effects">Turn off effects</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I decided to try the css approach for animation using http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp as a guide.

All I did was add the css animation:

```
i.fly {
  -webkit-animation-name: flying;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: flying;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flying {
  0% {
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    right: -50px;
    bottom: 50px;
  }
}

@keyframes flying {
  0% {
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    right: -50px;
    bottom: 50px;
  }
}
```

on js:

```
$("#travel").toggleClass("fly");
```

Most important thing was to toggle the effect with the button